# Problem in using Remote Validation in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to check uniqueness of Identity `PhoneNumber` with Remote attribute on `DTO` or `Model` in `Api` controller but seems not working and the `sqlException` get triggered

My `AuthController` is inside of Api Folder but I try with a separate `ValidatorController` inside of default Controllers folder

I used the convention of Remote attribute that has advised in Microsoft documentations

```
// My Dto
namespace Imah.Api.API.Dto.Requests
{
    public class PasswordlessLoginRequest
    {        
        public User User { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "the phone number is empty")]
        [Remote(action: "IsPhoneNumberExist", controller: "Auth")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}

// User Model
public class User : IdentityUser<int>, ITrackable
    {
        [Remote(action: "IsPhoneNumberExist", controller: "Auth")]
        public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    }

// AuthController
[AllowAnonymous]
    public class AuthController : ApiControllerBase
    {


public AuthController(AuthService authService, SignInManager<User> signInManager,
            IConfiguration config, UserManager<User> userManager,
        IMapper mapper, INotificationService notifyService, IUserRepository repo)
        {

        }



        [HttpPost("register")]        
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(
            PasswordlessLoginRequest userForRegisterDto)
        {


                var user = new User { PhoneNumber = userForRegisterDto.PhoneNumber };

                RegisterParams registerParams = new RegisterParams
                {
                    User = user,
                };

                var code = await _authService.Register(registerParams);
                var userToReutrn = _mapper.Map<UserForListDto>(user);
                if (code != null)
                {

                    // Send authCode to user
                    _notifyService.Notify(user, code);

                    return Ok(userToReutrn);
                }

            return BadRequest("Error");


        }

public IActionResult IsPhoneNumberExist([Bind(Prefix = "User.PhoneNumber")]string PhoneNumber)
        {
         return Json(data: $"A user phone number {PhoneNumber} already exists.");

           //var user = _repo.GetUserByPhone(PhoneNumber).Result;
           //if (user != null)
           //{
           // return Json(data: $"A user phone number {PhoneNumber} already exists.");
           //}
           //else
           //{
            //     return Json(data: true);
            //}
        }
}
```

Comment: For remote validation to work you need to use ValidationScripts added in your view's script section `@section scripts{
@Html.Partial("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
}` Otherwise there is no way that you could validate before posting your model.

Comment: @Dennis1679 This controller is used by api and has no views

Comment: then you have the wrong idea about Remote Validation. Remote validation is a `client-side validation
technique` that invokes an action method on the server to perform validation. In other words, you use this to validate user input in their browser. You don't use it after it has been posted (submitted) to your controller (server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem with Remote Validation. The problem is you're not completely understanding what Remote Validation is, or does.

Remote validation is a client-side validation technique that invokes an action method on the server to perform validation.

A common example of remote validation is to check whether a username is available in applications where such names must be unique when the user submits the data, and the client-side validation is performed.

Remote validation is performed in the background when a user is filling out a model where a property has the `Remote` attribute in a view. The user doesn’t have
to click the submit button and then wait for a new view to be rendered and be returned a possible error message explaining that the entered username is taken. Instead, it does a lightweight Ajax request to the server to validate if the username is taken and then returns a true/false value that the client-side jQuery validator will use to show the user they have entered a duplicate username.